# Get all duplicate child nodes in one parent node - Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a following xml file :

```
<Root>
 <Customers>
  <Customer>
   <Web>abc</Web>
   <Web>bcd</Web>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
   <Web>hjk</Web>
  </Customer>
 </Customers>
</Root>
```

- I want to get quantity of Web in only first Customer, not include the second one, the first Customer have 2 Web, the second one has only 1 Web, I used count() but It's returned quantity of all in xml file : 3 Webs
- When I use xpath with "//Web[1]", It shows 2 values : abc and hjk ; and with "//Web[2]", It shows : bcd. I want to extract one by one by xpath. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not 100% clear what your final goal is. But here some hints:

Q: I want to get quantity of Web in only first Customer
Try: `count(Customer[1]/Web)`

*When I use xpath with "//Web[1]", It shows 2 values* 
This is the first Web in each Customer.

*with "//Web[2]", It shows : bcd.* 
This are all second Web in all Customer. There is only one.

Q: *I want to extract one by one by xpath. Is there a way to do that?*
Try:`(//Web)[1]` for first of all.
`(//Web)[2]` for second of all.
`(//Web)[2]` ... and so on.